# leaflet TileWMS bounding

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have a TileWMS layer from geoserver. I'm trying to display it (properly) with leaflet.
The only problem is that it seems that THE WHOLE WORLD map is around my TileWMS layer. So I get a WHOLE blank area around my layer.

What I'd like to do is to display ONLY the tile layer in some sort of box ; like a container. I have tried `mapfitbounds` with the coordiantes of the bounds for my TileWMS layer. I helped a bit BUT the blank area is still there.

How can I get rid of the blank and only have my TileWMS layer (BTW I sure the blank is not comming from my WMS layer as I edited it with Qgis )

Below is my JS and HTML and the div off the map(with border-style :solid)

**Javascript**

```
function init(){
var map = L.map('map');

var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/MYPROJECT/wms', {
    layers: 'MY_WORKSPACE:MY_LAYER'
}).addTo(map);

map.setView(new L.LatLng(5.4919, -3.8174), 16);

 map.fitBounds([
    [5.4304, -4.0268],
    [5.3207, -3.9060]
]);

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
    <!--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /--> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mystyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet/leaflet.css">
    <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="MyJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<div id="map"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

**MAP**

The yellow area is my TileWMS and the div is border-style solid. So we can see the not needed blank space

[My map displayed in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLa8N.png)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get rid of the blank and only have my TileWMS layer

The white space is part of your WMS images.

> (BTW I sure the blank is not comming from my WMS layer as I edited it with Qgis )

No, that's no guarantee that the WMS server will output images with a transparent background. Have you tried inspecting your browser's network requests, and seeing if the images have a transparent background? I'm fairly sure your Qgis and your Leaflet are requesting the WMS images in a slightly different way.

Make sure to use the `transparent` WMS parameter, and make sure your geoserver supports it.